# Google Scripts Sheets Conditional Sorting

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I just recently discovered Google Scripts, and I was wondering if there was a way to sort by a function. For example, if the values in column B were in the range of all real numbers, would there be a way to sort the rows by increasing b^2? Obviously in this scenario it would be the same as sorting by ascending absolute value but this is just an example. I have Java experience so I don't have a problem writing the actual function, but I just need to get used to all the new functions. I'm already aware range.sort(x) sorts the rows by increasing x, but after a bit of searching I couldn't find a way to sort by a function of the values in a column. For example, if column A contains the name of people and B contains their score in a game. So A1:A4 = [A, B, C, D] and B1:B4 = [3, -1, -4, 5] and you want to sort them by increasing square of the value in the B column. So it would order them A1:A4 = [B, A, C, D] and B1:B4 = [-1, 3, -4, 5]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief descriptionof your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. By the way, posts on this site should include only one question.

Comment: Welcome. Google Sheets has two functions for sorting: `sort()` and `sortn()` - these are called from a spreadsheet cell, not from a script - [doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=3105422)

Comment: You ask if it is possible to _sort the rows by increasing b^2_ and _I'm already aware range.sort(x) sorts the rows by increasing x_. Your use of the word "increasing" is a problem - sort does not work like this - but perhaps you intend a different meaning. Would you please edit your question to clarify what you mean by "increasing b^2" and "increasing x"; it would be useful if you gave an example of how you want to sort data, and describe how a successful outcome would appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

`=query(A1:B4,"select A, (B*B) label (B*B) ''")`